# fetch mfData value in the ts file to carry operation on it in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I have this code to iterate data from  stacklist_table which is a json array and display it in a table format. stacklist_table is full list of all the objects. But i dont need all objects so I have applied some pipe.  And then my final value is kept it #stacklist which is iterated below to display columns and rows.

```
<table class="table" [mfData]="stacklist_table| selectedcolumn | search : searchQuery | filter: addFilter : selected" #stacklist="mfDataTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th *ngFor="let colValues of stacklist.data | column: '' : ''">
                    <mfDefaultSorter by="{{colValues}}">{{colValues|translate}}</mfDefaultSorter>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr draggable *ngFor="let stack of stacklist.data" [dragOverClass]="'drag-over-border'" [dragData]="stack" [class.active]="checkIfStackElementIsSelected(stack)" (click)="setStacklistRow(stack)">
                  <td *ngFor="let rowValues of stack | row">{{ rowValues }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Can I access this #stacklist value in my backend typescript file?
I need the final stacklist after all the pipes applied in typescript file. How can I go about it?

Comment: You could also apply your pipes in your `component.ts` if you need that data with the `@Pipe` applied

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the data after pipes are applied in your `component.ts`, you can apply pipes directly in your component.

```
import { MyCustomPipe } from './my-custom.pipe';

export class MyClass {
   constructor(private customPipe: MyCustomPipe){
     this.pipeAppliedData = this.customPipe.transform(someData); // this will be like doing in template "someData | MyCustomPipe"
   }       
}
```

At this point, you could do whatever you need to do with your data with pipes applied (`this.pipeAppliedData`) and then use `this.pipeAppliedData` in your template. This way you are using pipes once (in your component) and you use the result in both sides: template and component.

Comment: Its like applying pipe twice on same list. Is that file?

Comment: Well, you could apply it in component if you need to use it for something else and then, the resulting data you can use it in your template. If you don't need the data with the pipes applied inside your component then just use the pipes as intended: In the template. What I gave you is a solution for using pipes inside the component and I thought that this was what you wanted/needed. :D

Comment: @MendonAshwini I updated my answer, check it out! ;) Hope it helps mate! ;)

Comment: yes. I will implement this and remove pipe from template

Comment: @MendonAshwini Nice! Let me know how it goes. I used this for translations. But is always better to use `@Pipe` in your template though. Good luck! ;)

Comment: 1 more doubt is.. my data which is iterated and shown in table depends on pagination. So how will I get this information in component. Like which page data is shown and n how many rows are shown

Comment: I strongly suggest you that you use DataTables for that.

Comment: So How do I access this data in component in case of DataTables?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to it and finding it too complicated. I need to get elements shown in the list on which page it is(like 1st page or 2nd page )

Comment: @MendonAshwini Hi! I think I have succesfully answered your original question, right? If you think so, please mark it as answered so people know this question has been succesfully answered and can learn about it. About the DataTables, try using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable . Try that out, and if you encounter any problems don't hesitate to post a new question with the new problem and we will all be very glad to help you out. Wish you luck! ;)